# calling restfulwebservice from java script using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

i am trying to call a restful webservice which return jsonobject in  string format ..the request is send to the server but here i am not getting the response can anyone help me?
 i am testing in chrome browser..

```
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 var url = "http://localhost:8080/DataWeb/rest/datastore/getData";
 xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 var res=xmlhttp.responseText;
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
           document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      } else {
           document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.readyState +","+ xmlhttp.status;
      }
 }
```

Comment: Have you ensured that your service actually returns the correct data? You can use something like [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/) to test this.

Comment: ya when hit the url from browser it displaying data..

Answer (score 0):

What you mean with "no response"? No string in responseText or the code inside the if() is never executed? Personally, I would switch the order of send() and xmlhttp.onreadystatechange(), first define the function to handle onreadystatechange and then send the request.

To investigate the request, you can print it to the console (inside the onreadystatechange)

```
console.log(xmlhttp)
```

to see what it actually contains

Comment: i am getting in  onreaddystatechange xmlhttp.readyState=4 and xmlhttp.status=0

Comment: just now i check the same code with IE ,it's working i amgetting the result ..may be problem with chrome... thanx for replys

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to first assign the 'onreadystatechange' handler and only then to call 'send' method. Otherwise the request executes before you handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://localhost:8080/DataWeb/rest/datastore/getData";
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.readyState +","+ xmlhttp.status;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET",url);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Also, consider using a library, such as jQuery, so you don't have to handle all this boilerplate coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this jquery code ,

```
 $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "http://localhost:8080/DataWeb/rest/datastore/getData",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml){
    $("#myDiv").html(xml);
  }   
});
```

This may solve the problem of writing different codes for different browsers.

Note: Include latest jquery.js file before writing the above script in your page.

Thanks